# How would I cycle through all child nodes in Firebase and read all data nodes inside them in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have a system where each user has permissions to read one or more specific nodes (but not all). How would I set up so I can cycle through all the child nodes in my database when reading and it will subsequently only read the ones the user has permission for?

Thanks so much!

This is what I have to currently:
(There are more than 2 stores)

```
var database = firebase.database();
var storeOneRef = database.ref().child('storeOne');
var storeTwoRef = database.ref().child('storeTwo');

var allStores = [ { ref: storeOneRef, name: 'storeOne'},
                    { ref: storeTwoRef, name: 'storeTwo'} ];
for (var i = 0; i < allStores.length; i++) {
    allStores[i].ref.once('value', (snapshot) => {
        var data = snapshot.val();
    });
}
```

This is what the database looks like:
[image: database screenshot]

Comment: This is very vague.  What's your database structure? Are you using security rules?  If so, what are they?  What code have you already tried, and if so, what was the problem?

Comment: For example: Each store has a child node and then inside that node there are sales. When a retailer wants to see their sales, they would only want to see their own. How would I be able to have a blanket way of doing that instead of specifying the specific node?

Comment: You haven't defined how a retailer knows which sales are their own.  What is your database structure?  Are you using security rules?  You need to define these things before getting at your conclusion.  There is no "blanket solution" that automatically lets you filter and block at the same time.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#rules_are_not_filters

Comment: Each retailer user has a login which will be authenticated using firebase database rules to one retailer child node. Each retailer child node has multiple sales. Each sale has multiple fields describing date, price etc etc.

Comment: It sounds like you don't have a problem if sales are stored underneath the retailer.  They would already be authorized to read their own sales.

Comment: If I'm misunderstanding your database and rules, please edit your question to show more explicitly what you have going on.  A diagram of the database with actual rules would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks @DougStevenson I edited it with more information.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your database has all sales nodes underneath the store/retail node to which they belong.  If one of your store/retailers already has read access to their own node, then they will unconditionally have access to all their own sales.  There is actually nothing you can do to prevent this.  If someone has read access at any node, they implicitly have read access to all child nodes under that one.

Comment: Yep correct, that is all fine! I was just wondering if there was a better way to do this instead of how I am currently doing it in that code excerpt, as I have to create a new ref every time a new retailer joins.

Comment: That's not really what your original question is asking.  Right now, the answer to your question is as I stated: you have no problems iterating children at the node in question.  I'd suggest starting over and asking a new question that describes the problem you're running into.